# Change Outlook's Default Address Book for all users

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell

I have a PowerShell command to change the Outlook address book to GlobalUser:

Here is the command:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046\" -Name 00033d1b -Value ([byte[]](0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00)
```

And I would like it to be in All user and not in Global User
I would just have to change the Value (byte[])

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Base on my research, i found the registry "00033d1b" can only be set to GAL or Contacts folder, as mentioned by @JadeLiang-MSFT in this [thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/321593/change-outlook-address-book-outlook-365.html#:%7E:text=Location%20%3AHKEY_CURRENT_USER%5CSOFTWARE,work%20for%20you.). And i didn't find such a method to change the default address book to All user for all users. I'm afraid you need to [change it manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-default-address-book-53b3ce7a-9d35-4e27-9e37-57979778fe5b).

[image]